# how to set Laravel 5.1 project url?

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.1  , when I want to use laravel in localhost ( wampserver)
I can access to my project by this address :

by running `php artisan serve` command : 
http://localhost:8000

and in this way every thing is ok and all packages work well ! 
but when I do not want to   run `php artisan serve` I can access to project by removing public from url by [this way](http://tutsnare.com/remove-public-from-url-laravel/) by this address :
http://localhost/myblog
and also I can upload my project on shared hosting easily ! but I have big problem here ! when I want to use filemanager package or other packages , I noticed that thay can not recognize project url.
for example they consider http://localhost is the project's url  ! 
how can I  fix this ? I don't want to use SSH and run composer on hosting !

Comment: On shared hosting you don't have anything special to do for Laravel. Put the content of your Laravel `public` folder in `public_html` and all other folders and files from your project put them direct in your `root` directory. Everything should work just fine. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

in your **config/app.php** change url and check

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Hamel Raj's answer you can also change this from your `.env` file in the root folder of your project.

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

If the line is not there you can just add it.

This would many times be much more prefered since you can chance the app url per environment you're working in.